# AWS CLI output append to json file

Tags: text-processing, json

I have a `sample.json` with the content below :

```json
{key:value}
```

I want the AWS secrets CLI command output (`secretstring json object`)

```json
{
user:name,
pass:word 
}
```

to be appended to my JSON file above so that the file now becomes

```json
{
key:value,
user:name,
pass:word
}
```

I tried `jq` but it just overwrites my json file with the command output with `\` as escape characters for quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are actually dealing with JSON data (none of the shown strings in the question is valid JSON):

```bash
some-json-generating-command | jq -s add sample.json - | sponge sample.json
```

... where `some-json-generating-command` is some command generating JSON output and `sample.json` is your JSON document.

This pipeline would cause `jq` to read your file together with the output of the command on the left-hand-side of the pipeline into two separate elements of an array.  It would then merge those two elements using the `add` instruction.  The generated output would then be sent to GNU `sponge` which would write the result back into the `sample.json` file (`jq` can't do in-place editing).

Testing:

```bash
$ jq -c . sample.json
{"key":"value"}
$ jq -c . command-output.json
{"user":"name","pass":"word"}
```

```bash
$ cat command-output.json | jq -s add sample.json - | sponge sample.json
$ cat sample.json
{
  "key": "value",
  "user": "name",
  "pass": "word"
}
```

Without GNU `sponge`, run the pipeline on a copy of your `sample.json` file and write the output to the original name, then remove the temporary file if the pipeline ran sucessfully:

```
cp sample.json sample.tmp
some-json-generating-command | jq -s add sample.tmp - >sample.json && rm -f sample.tmp
```